# PHP file_get_contents vulnerability

Tags: php, security

I'm assessing security of a webportal for a client and I found a vulnerability.

This is the PHP code:

```
echo(file_get_contents("template/data/" $_GET['id']));
```

I was able to successfully read ../../../index.php, config.php etc.

But I just want to be able to prove that this bug is more critical than reading configs. I read the MySQL user/pass, but I can't connect to it since its listening on localhost only. All other codes I read, didn't lead to anything. So basically all I got was just some source code which was kinda no secret.

I can't do php filter stuff because it has "template/data/" in the beginning of string.

What else can be done with this vulnerable piece of code? Any ideas?

Comment: Does the application allow you to upload files? If so, can you upload your own PHP file (that **does** do something interesting with the database) and execute it? If not, can you include files outside the application (e.g. `../../../../../../../../etc/passwd`)?

Comment: a) I included /etc/passwd, still doesn't lead to anything real really. b) I can't upload, but even if I can, how do I execute it? file_get_contents doesn't execute PHP codes, it just reads and spits them out as plain text

Comment: P.S. This might be off-topic for SO since it doesn't involve a specific programming problem, and might be more appropriate at [security](https://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Well, it should have given you a list of users that actually exist on the server, narrowing down your list of potential users to try to attack an SSH connection with

Comment: You can't really "hack" SSH and server only have port 80/443 open. I was wondering if file_get_contents can do something more

Comment: I would say this is not a vulnerability with `file_get_contents` but a vulnerability of the coder ***NOT PROPERLY SECURING USER GIVEN DATA***. The issue is with the coder not the function. The function does exactly as it intends.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This question is a broad general aspect and doesn't deal with a specific coding instance, instead this topic could be raised on the [Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vulnerability is what it is. You can't make it more dangerous just because you want to. But it gives you a lot of information, as you already figured out.

Additionally it can be very dangerous in the right environment. Every SSRF bug in the portal should give you full control over the database; and those bugs are frequently considered low impact/low priority on their own.

It can also be interesting to check what other applications are running on the same server. A vBulletin forum? You can leak `COOKIE_SALT`, and sign whatever malicious data you want with it; your data will be passed to `unserialize`. A wordpress blog? Lots of plugins store secrets as PHP constants, and once you know those secrets you can take over the server.

The most important message you have to get across to your client is that even if this bug just leaks information now, it can become much more dangerous in the future. Even if he just installs mainstream software.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed, I just wanted to confirm that we can't really do more with this bug.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't do php filter stuff because it has "template/data/" in the beginning of string.

You can validate the ID.  This should always be done with values passed by POST and GET:

```
$template_id = $_GET['id'];
if (strlen($template_id) < 1 || $template_id[0] === '.')
{
    echo 'Invalid template ID';
    die;
]
echo(file_get_contents("template/data/$template_id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can read configs to get a valid username and password, I'd say your two main vulnerabilities at that point are password reuse (e.g. see if there's other places to log in and use the same password, which could give more access) or social engineering. You could use access to the filesystem to "prove" to someone that you're an admin or something and try to gain further access that way.

It might not seem like a huge vulnerability at first but access to hidden information is a big hole in the armor.